# What should I do with an answer on my question which has got upvote but not a solution to my question rather It is misleading with that upvote?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I have a bounty question and someone posted an answer and got some up votes, but for my problem the answer is not applicable.

I can notice people are getting confused with that answer as it has up votes. It is making people feel the answer is really helpful so that is having up votes and they should follow same way to get the solution with some improvements.so People are trying to enhance that answer.

However the post is never going to lead to an answer for my question.

What are my options to inform the OP and the community of the issue with the answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Great chance your question is the problem, not the answer.

First start with a comment on the answer explaining why the answer doesn't work for your situation. The responses to that might make clear why the OP assumed their answer could work for you.

Use the collected feedback to improve your question, ruling out the mishap that took the first answerer by surprise. That will also bump your question, hopefully leading to some new attention

If the both of you can't work out the root cause of the misunderstanding leave a down vote on the answer and use clear and verifiable arguments/evidence why the answer is not good enough.

Beyond this there is not much else you can do.

Comment: Actually I was discussing with the person who had asked the question and during the discussion I got, he do not think the answer already given with upvotes is a whole different thing from what he want to get.Then the same question , I asked my self that what I should in that situation .

Comment: I suggested him something like this , but still I though to learn it .

Comment: Good advice but "great chance"? One of the best things I ever learned in this online life came from a manager at Amazon: Answer the question that was asked, not the question you wish was asked. Plenty of respondents on SO attempt to shoehorn problems into favored libraries and practices without reading questions thoroughly.

Answer (score -1):

If the answer has an upvote it was useful to *someone*. Whether it actually solves your question is not relevant to the upvote.

If the upvoted answer does not solve your question, edit **your question** to explain why the upvoted answer is not applicable.

Comment: `edit your question to explain why the upvoted answer is not applicable. `Pretty please no! Clarifying the question to get an answer to it is the only acceptable course of action.

Comment: *"If the answer has an upvote it was useful to someone"* unless the upvote came from a sock of course.

Comment: @KevinB Well yes, but perhaps you're more cynical than I. :)